# Google Colab 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'universe_domain'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

When trying to use google colab with google speech to text (from google sample notebook :

I get :

```
if credentials:
--> 505             credentials_universe = credentials.universe_domain
    506             if client_universe != credentials_universe:
    507                 default_universe = SpeechClient._DEFAULT_UNIVERSE

AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'universe_domain'
```

Here is the python code :

First I login using colab "auth" :

```py
!pip install -q google-cloud-speech
from google.cloud import speech

!pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib

from google.colab import auth
gcp_project_id = 'my-gcp-project'
auth.authenticate_user(project_id=gcp_project_id)
```

Then I activate speech api from gcp :

```py
!gcloud services enable speech.googleapis.com
```

I configure the speech recognition :

```py
from google.cloud import speech

def speech_to_text(
    config: speech.RecognitionConfig,
    audio: speech.RecognitionAudio,
) -> speech.RecognizeResponse:
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    # Synchronous speech recognition request
    response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)

    return response

config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    language_code="fr",
    enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
)
```

Finally I record some sound to transcript :

```py
!pip install ipywebrtc

import io
from ipywebrtc import AudioRecorder, CameraStream

# create a microphone stream
camera = CameraStream(constraints={'audio': True, 'video':False})
recorder = AudioRecorder(stream=camera)
recorded_audio = recorder.audio.value
audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(
    content=recorded_audio,
)
```

And here is the problematic piece of code, when I actually try to use the google api :

```py
processing_results = speech_to_text(config, audio)
```

Comment: Did you run the `!gcloud auth application-default login` to get Application Default Credentials (ADC) before calling `auth` module?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when working on GoogleVertexAISearchRetriever.

According to https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/12254,
the version of google-auth that you're using does not expose universe_domain as a property of credentials.

Simply upgrading google-auth to the latest version can fix the issue.

```
pip install --upgrade google-auth
```

Don't forget to restart Python after the upgrade.